# iOS WKWebView File upload failure on iPhone

Tags: ios, file-io, upload, wkwebview, filepicker

In our app we use WKWebView to display web contents, but the file upload works incorrectly.
On iPhone we could browse from photo library (or take picture) but after the file has been selected, a thumbnail image shows up on the right side of the file input and after that the webpage quickly (or as I see, the whole ViewController) reloads itself (and webpage with th default URL). No image uploaded to server.

BUT!!
On iPad with the same OS version we could successful upload photo or captured image.

Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

My bad! In the viewWillAppear function I load an url. So every time when the app come back from background, or another app gives back the control, this lifecycle event will be called, therefor in my case the webview always reload the default url.

Comment: Man, your saved me! Thank you.
Such a silly mistake we made.

Comment: same goes with 'viewDidAppear', I have been caught more than once.